# Search windows by default application

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search

Is there a way to search for files in windows explorer according to the application they open with; I want to find all files that open with Excel by default, as well as all that open with Notepad++

Comment: There are registry entries for file system associations. Why are you actually interested in doing this?

Comment: Application associations for files are  determined by file exension. So for Notepad, search for `*.txt`.